# There is a file which is having 10 columns delimeted with space.I want to insert comma for first six columns only

Tags: bash

I have a file like below. But for first file columns i want to put comma while printing and rest of the columns should print with space. Is there anyway i can achieve through `sed` or `awk` command?

```
$ cat testing
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Google "sed replace n times". The first hit is your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add a comma on first column only:

```
sed -i 's/ /,/' testing
```

to do it on the first six:

```
rev testing | sed  's/ /,/g4' |rev
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 'eval "s/ /,/;"x5' < testing
```